# How to Install ServiceStack.Host.AspNet Into a Legacy Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I just installed the **ServiceStack** NuGet package **ServiceStack.Host.AspNet** into an existing legacy VB.NET Web Forms site. After cleaning, then running the project I am being prompted with this text

Forbidden
Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.PathInfo:
 
Request.QueryString: ReturnUrl=%2f
Request.RawUrl: /LoginPersonal.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: True
App.WebHostPhysicalPath: < *Path to website* >
App.WebHostRootFileNames: [ *List of every file and folder in the root of the application*]
App.DefaultRootFileName: default.htm

instead of my log-in page.

What is the best approach to slowly integrate SS into the site without breaking existing functionality, yet benefiting from SS Session, Cache, ORM, and Serialization?

**UPDATE**

The solution that ended up working was in the wiki all along, except it was missing the step about removing the original handler created by NuGet. I have since update the wiki to reflect this use case.

-Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the custom path as per [this wiki article](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework)?

Comment: I had read that but discounted it as it seemed to imply it was more of an issue with MVC type apps, when you mentioned it I tried the changes but to no avail. sorry

Comment: The key to it was finding the installed handler that nuget inserted and removing it, then the steps in the article worked.. thank you